# Joining 3 Tables With Multiple Column Connections

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I am struggling to get the correct syntax for what I need and wondered if anyone could help?

I have 3 tables: users, owneditems and shopitems

From users I need to get userid and city

From owneditems I need to get userid and itemid

From shopitems I need to get id and city

---

userid on owneditems and users will be the same

itemid on owneditems will be the same as id on shopitems

city on shopitems and users will be the same

---

What I'm after is to find out which city the users are in and tie up which items they own in that city.

The syntax I tried using was

```
SELECT users.city, users.id, shopitems.city, shopitems.id, owneditems.itemid, owneditems.userid 
FROM users, shopitems, owneditems 
WHERE users.city = shopitems.city 
  AND owneditems.itemid = shopitems.it 
  AND users.id = owneditems.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but have you tried using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN`:

```
select u.city, 
    u.id, 
    s.city, 
    s.id, 
    o.itemid, 
    o.userid
from users u
left join owneditems o
    on u.id = o.userid
left join shopitems s
    on u.city = s.sity
    and o.itemid = s.itemid
```

Comment: I think I got it in the end 

SELECT users.city, users.id, shopitems.city, shopitems.id, owneditems.itemid, owneditems.userid FROM users, shopitems, owneditems WHERE users.city = shopitems.city AND owneditems.itemid = shopitems.id AND users.id = owneditems.userid AND users.city = 1 AND users.id = 93074